# Multidimensional array or cell array in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I want to create a multidimensional array `A` in Matlab of dimension `NxMxG` with `N,M,G` very large (e.g. `10^6`).

Then I need to access `A`in a loop as

```
for g=1:G
    Atemp=A(:,:,g);
    %etc etc
end
```

What is more convenient in terms of speed and memory between storing the values of `A` in a multidimensional array or in a cell array?

Comment: What are you storing in the *matrix*?

Comment: I store numbers

Comment: If the data is uniform in size and type there is no reason to use a cell array.

Comment: Array must be consecutive in memory, and cell array does not. It is important in 32 bits version of Matalb (cell array has advantage). When I type `memory` command in my 64 bit Matalb, `Maximum possible array` equals `Memory available for all arrays`, so I guess for 64 bit there is no advantage using cell array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you always loop on *slices* in the same way, and process them one at a time, as your bit of code seem to suggest, then the performance should be roughly equivalent.
2. If you really intend to store 1e6x1e6x1e6 double's, Matlab is <s>definitely</s> *probably* not your tool. However, if *slices* are sparse, then it's probably a bit more efficient to store them as a cell array, so Matlab does not have to search the full 3D space when *"cutting"* the *slice*, and `Atemp=A{g};` simply copies a sparse matrix.
3. If you are working on full (nonsparse) *slices* then probably you should load/save your slice to disk and use instead a function/support class which loads from file: `Atemp=A(g);`. Mind that text loading takes up much more time than loading a binary file: so choose your file format carefully!

Comment: Thank you. May I ask you further clarifications on what do you mean by `` then probably you should load/save your slice to disk and use instead a function/support class which loads from file: Atemp=A(g)''. What should I save and what should I load exactly? How can I save in a binary format?

Comment: Assuming your data is a full `NxMxG` matrix with `N,M,G=1e6`, then you clearly cannot load the whole data in memory (probably also disk space is a problem there). If you want to be able to work with the data, I think you should save one file for each slice, then load them. If your data is built outside of Matlab, you can prepare e.g. a set of `.csv` files and load them in Matlab. I suggest a pre-run of `Atmp=csvread('file000001.csv'); save('file000001.mat','Atmp')` before working. `save` will by default use a binary format.

Answer (score 0):

If you use numbers, a multidimensional array is the right thing to use. A cell array also allows other types, so is less optimised for numbers only. Because you are using very large arrays, maybe a [sparse matrix](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sparse.html) may be appropriate for you.

Comment: Sparse matrices are only useful when a large percentage of the array is zero. Attempting to use it with a dense matrix will incur a significant performance penalty.

Comment: Of course, but because he is using very high dimensions, I assumed the matrix will be probably sparse. A plain 10^6 x 10^6 x 10^6 will not fit in memory.

Answer (score 0):

First, note that neither pick will let you handle 10^18 values. You don't have exabytes of storage, let alone memory.

If you will ONLY ever use it as `Atemp = A(:,:,g);` with N and M always the same size for all g, having it multi-dimensional or cell shouldn't change anything meaningful as far as performance goes. N-D will be probably a bit faster, but nothing significant.

Obviously, if you ever want to have computation with different sizes of N, M depending on g, you need to pick cell array. And if you want to have computation with say `Atemp = squeeze(A(:,g,:));` N-D array is clear choice here.

So, choice most likely depends if you prefer doing `A(:,:,g)` or `A{g};`, which depends on your meaning of data. Say if you have weather data and currently only care about what happens at specific height (not what happens between the layers), `A(:,:,g)` is clearly more sensible. It is possible you will require inter-layer calculations at some point. But if you have instead g meaning different measurement sites gathering data, A{g} should be used to pick the site. You will likely have some sites larger or smaller eventually.